# How To Import or Parse JWK From File (string) into a KeyObject in Node?

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

The jwk is saved to file like:

```
let jwk = keyObject.export({format:'jwk'})
fs.writeFileSync(JWK_PATH, JSON.stringify(jwk));
```

But how do you parse the jwk string back in to a `KeyObject`?

`KeyObject.from(jwkString)` throws `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be an instance of CryptoKey.`.

let `key = createSecretKey(jwkString,'base64url');` creates erroneous result w invalid key length.

I am passing the key to the `createCipheriv` method successfully if I pass just the "k" property of the JWK but `createCipheriv` accepts `KeyObjects` and it seems like best practice to hold the keys in the (secret) `KeyObject` rather than as a string? I can't find an import except in the WebCrypto/Subtle module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symmetric key is ultimately simply a byte sequence (raw or encoded with a binary-to-text encoding). For a symmetric key in JWK format (s. e.g. [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517.html#appendix-A.3)), the raw key is stored Base64url encoded in `k` (*key value*).

So importing into a `KeyObject` (more precisely `SecretKeyObject`) is easily possible with ([here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatesecretkeykey-encoding)):

```js
crypto.createSecretKey(aesKeyJwk.k, 'base64url')
```

Example:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto')

// Generate symmetric 32 bytes AES key for AES-256, wrapped in SecretKeyObject
var aesKey = crypto.generateKeySync('aes', {length: 256})

// Export as JWK
var aesKeyJwk = aesKey.export({format: 'jwk'})

// Import JWK into a SecretKeyObject 
var aesKeyReloaded = crypto.createSecretKey(aesKeyJwk.k, 'base64url')

// Test
var plaintext = Buffer.from('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'utf8')
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', aesKey, iv)                        // encrypt with aeskey
var ciphertext = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(plaintext), cipher.final()])
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', aesKeyReloaded, iv)            // decrypt with aesKeyReloaded, proving that the same raw key is wrapped
var decryptedText = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(ciphertext), decipher.final()])

// Output
console.log(aesKey)                           // SecretKeyObject { [Symbol(kKeyType)]: 'secret' }
console.log(aesKeyJwk)                        // e.g. { kty: 'oct', k: 'Y4mR6UP1NmI0TS3uVu9F6SWCb-lvQhlykFqPFATQ3vo' } // k (key value) contains the Base64 url encoded raw key, kty contains the key type, oct (octet secuence) denotes a symmetric key
console.log(aesKeyReloaded)                   // SecretKeyObject { [Symbol(kKeyType)]: 'secret' }
console.log(decryptedText.toString('utf8'))   // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Thanks. Passing the `.k` property of the JWK to `createSecretKey` was what worked. It leaves me wondering why the WebCrypto keys include the `keyUsages` property? That's another question though. Thanks.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston - A key/key pair should not be used for different purposes (see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12090)). The WebCrypto API implements this principle by requiring algorithm (e.g. `RSA-OAEP`) and key usages (`['encrypt', 'decrypt']`) to be defined for each key/key pair (e.g. in [`generateKey(algorithm,..., keyUsages)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey)).